# How do you find values from different worksheets based on a criteria and return a particular cell value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been given a workbook comprising of three worksheets i.e `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`. My task is to lookup `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` based on `Column A` of `Sheet1`, find a `match` in `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` then pupulate
Columns `D`, `E`, `F` of `Sheet1` with values from Column `C` in `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`. I hope this is clear enough. Please advise otherwise. Thanks SO
My attempt is by using a combination of `IF`, `IFERROR` and `VLOOKUP` fuctions in cells of `D` `E` and `F` of `Sheet1` but am getting `0` i.e:

**Column D:**

`=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$6, 3,FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet3!$A$2:$E$6,3,FALSE), "0"))=10, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$6, 3,FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet3!$A$2:$E$6,3,FALSE), "0")), "0")`

**Column E:**

`=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$6, 3,FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet3!$A$2:$E$6,3,FALSE), "0"))=12, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$6, 3,FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet3!$A$2:$E$6,3,FALSE), "0")), "0")`

**Column F:**

`=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$6, 3,FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet3!$A$2:$E$6,3,FALSE), "0"))=15, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$6, 3,FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet3!$A$2:$E$6,3,FALSE), "0")), "0")`

`Sheet2:`

[image]

`Sheet3:`

[image]

`Expected:`

[image]

**Update with help from @basic:**

[image]

Comment: I can see two problems. 1. Vlookup will always return first row so the function you are using will never return anything after that, and 2ndly you are checking the rate which is in column 4, but you are using 3 in column# argument

Comment: I have thought of `IF(Sheet2!D2=10,Sheet2!C2,IF(Sheet3!D2=10,Sheet3!C2,0))` but I am not sure of matching it with the ID column

Comment: Do you have Excel 365?  This seems like it would be much easier if you can use `Filter`, `Unique` and other newer formula.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have office 365 on a different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following array formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((CHOOSE({1;2},Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,Sheet3!$A$2:$A$6)=$A22)*(CHOOSE({1;2},Sheet2!$D$2:$D$6,Sheet3!$D$2:$D$6)=--(RIGHT(C$21,2)))*CHOOSE({1;2},Sheet2!$C$2:$C$6,Sheet3!$C$2:$C$6),0))`

Enter it with `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter` then copy right and down.

[image]

Comment: I have done just that, but I am getting `0` for all the cells.

Comment: @WKI I assume that then the data is different from what is shown in the example. Share workbook with data returning ```0```.

Comment: I am not sure about how to share files on SO. I have updated the OP please see above. I can see your solution refers to cell `A22` which is not used in the workbook. The data remains the same. as in the OP. Thanks

Comment: @WKI On SO you can't. Share on OneDrive or GoogleDrive. This is mine [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BiUqlw7a0azOkMBAJCNGqBXvxjkeAGDR/view?usp=sharing) with working formula.

Comment: forgive me but I have forgot that I had to change `Sheet3` from your formula to `Sheet1` since my main Worksheet is `Sheet1` I can see clearly now. Many thanks and happy .xlsx